# Why isn't jQuery removeClass working with a click function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to understand why removeClass isn't removing the active class when I click on another li. If it were the same li then I could use siblings to remove the class but sadly that doesn't work here either.

I'd like to understand this simple problem that I'm having.

```js
$('.r-picker li').click(function(){
  $('.r-picker li .data.active').removeClass('active');
  $('.r-picker li .data').addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r-picker">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="data">me1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="data">me1</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Lb65e/125/

Comment: My guess is that it is working. But the statement that follows the `.removeClass()`, adds the `active` class back to all `li .data` elements, including the one you just removed the class from...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z_acharki/Lb65e/128/)**.

You should use `$(this)` instead to refer to the clicked `li` :

```
$('.data', this).addClass('active');
```

Else the `.data` selector in your code will add class to all the elements with this class :

```
$('.r-picker li .data').addClass('active');
```

**NOTE :** Also you need to remove the class `active` from all the elments with class `data` when you click using :

```
$('.r-picker li .data').removeClass('active');
```

Hope this helps.

```js
$('.r-picker li').click(function() {
  $('.r-picker li .data').removeClass('active');
  $('.data', this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.active{
  color:red;
  font-size:25px;
  font-weight:bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="r-picker">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="data">me1</div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="data">me1</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Superb answer +1. Just for my clarification, what does the `$('.data', this)` statement do? I've never seen a selector written like that before. I'd guess that it searches for `.data` within the hierarchy of the current element context that `this` holds? Possibly shorthand for `$(this).find('.data')`? I'm wondering though if that guess is correct or really off base...

Comment: Yes that totally right @War10ck .. Thanks for your intervention :)

Comment: @War10ck `$("foo", bar)` is internally treated exactly like `$(bar).find("foo")`

Comment: @Pointy That's awesome. I didn't realize you could do that. It's a nice little shorthand.

Comment: That was perfect, thanks for the clear explanation, I really needed to understand it in details. +1 And thanks @War10ck for the question, that was something I needed answered too.

Answer (score 1):

Your code *is* working. Here's what it does:

```
 $('.r-picker li .data.active').removeClass('active');
```

That finds all elements with classes `data` and `active`, and removes `active` from all of them.

```
 $('.r-picker li .data').addClass('active');
```

That finds all elements with class `data` and adds the class `active` to all of them.

Thus, once that runs, you'll have added the class `active` back to all the elements from which it was removed.

In your event handler, when *adding* the class, you need to add it only to the `<li>` involved:

```
$(this).find(".data").addClass("active");
```

The jQuery event mechanism makes sure that `this` is bound to the DOM element involved with the event, so `$(this)` gives you a jQuery object for that element. The `.find()` method performs a DOM selector search starting from that element, so `$(this).find(".data")` finds elements with class `data` *only* in the DOM subtree beneath the clicked element.

Answer (score 1):

You need to highlight the div in the current `li`.

```
$('.r-picker li').click(function() {
    $('.r-picker li .data.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).find('.data').addClass('active');
});
```

Which first removes the active class, and then find the `div.data` in .`this` `li` and adds the class back...

Heres your fiddle updated and working: http://jsfiddle.net/Lb65e/126/